# Yii shell_exec yiic command run not working

Tags: php, unix, yii, shell-exec, yiic

I am trying to send large number of email notifications using `Yiic` and run `CConsoleCommand`.

Command is okay. There are no PHP errors. I can't run `linux` command using `shell_exec`.

Here is part of code

```
if ($post->save()) {

  chdir(Yii::app()->basePath);
  shell_exec('yiic makemasspost ' . $post->id . ' ' . $id . ' > log.txt & echo $!');

}
```

Comment: This is not related to Yii but to your PHP installation.

Comment: In case if reason is PHP installation.
What config i have to add to php.ini to enable shell_exec to run yiic commands ? 
Thank you.

Comment: The shell won't automatically find the yiic command (test this out by logging a new session to your home directory and run yiic). Please supply the full path to yiic and report back.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in going to linux from yii to run a command that actually runs an yii application again.

You can try running it directly from Yii

```
Yii::import('application.commands.*');
$command = new MyCommand("test", "test");
$command->run(null);
```